# Why does the compiler say a variable might not be initialized if it's required to be during a loop for it to pass?

Tags: java, while-loop, compiler-errors, initialization

I'm writing a program that counts the number of evens, odds and zeros in a user-defined integer.  Strangely, the compiler won't compile at all. It says "error: variable number might not have been initialized".

What doesn't make sense is, as far as I can tell, this loop will guarantee `number` ALWAYS is initialized. I know I can easily shut up the compiler by initializing at the declaration. I've always been told though it's usually a bad idea to initialize at declaration to help avoid logic errors. However my biggest scare/confusion in this is I don't know why it doesn't like it. If there is an exception, it will be caught before `validInput = true` ever happens, won't it? So then when the loop gets to the check, it'll restart since `validInput` will still be `false`. This isn't even a warning or anything; it's a hard-stop error. What am I missing or not seeing?

I've read other cases regarding if-checks, and this is different than where it's in a check that may or may not pass. This loop will ALWAYS pass eventually unless the program exits early somehow (in which case it won't reach the for-loop anyway). If this is a duplicate, can someone point me to the directly-related answer that I couldn't find? Thanks!

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    long number;
    boolean validInput = false;
    String numStr;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer:  ");
        numStr = input.next();

        try {
            number = Long.parseLong(numStr);
            validInput = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.print("That's not an integer. ");
        }
    } while (!validInput);


    // Break each digit up by dividing by powers of 10.
    int evens = 0, odds = 0, zeros = 0;
    for (long temp = number; temp > 0; temp /= 10)
    {
        int digit = (int)(temp % 10);

        if (digit == 0)
        {
            zeros++;
            System.out.println(digit + " is a zero digit.");
        }
        else if (digit % 2 == 0)
        {
            evens++;
            System.out.println(digit + " is an even digit.");
        }
        else
        {
            odds++;
            System.out.println(digit + " is an odd digit.");
        }
    }

    String evenStr = " even " + ((evens == 1) ? "digit" : "digits");
    String oddStr = " odd " + ((odds == 1) ? "digit" : "digits");
    String zeroStr = (zeros == 1) ? " zero" : " zeros";

    System.out.println(number + " has " + evens + evenStr + ", " + odds + oddStr + ", and "
            + zeros + zeroStr + ".");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler tries to say that `number` is not guaranteed to be initialized. For example, if the following statement throws an exception, the `number` will not be initialized:

```
number = Long.parseLong(numStr);
```

You then catch the exception, but `number` hasn't been "touched", so all further usages of that variable could potentially result in unexpected behavior or even exceptions.

Usual way to get rid of this is to assign the variable value right from the beginning:

```
long number = 0; // just an example, assign whatever value makes sense for you
```

**UPDATE**

Java specification may shed some more light on this topic, especially sections  [Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) and [Definite Assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html)

Comment: If the exception gets caught though, wouldn't it continue, then reach `while (!validInput);`, which would still be true since `validInput = true` would be skipped by the catch, and therefore repeat until validInput (and thus exception-free input) was provided and assigned to `number`?

Comment: This would be the case if compiler allowed you to compile and execute the code, however the standard compiler's behavior is to throw an error - it cannot analyze the code too deep to "spot" this.

Comment: You know, it is impossible for compiler to check all possible variants and combinations of variable values, program flows etc. - it is easier to throw an error and make programmer to "fix" the code...

Comment: I understand now that it's not working because it's "too difficult" for it. But I still don't really understand why. The compiler is already tracing through the program when compiling (doesn't it?), so it would have to see ahead of time if it was initialized at that point or not, wouldn't it? I don't see why it would need to check against _every_ variation like you're saying, or even any. Tracing through, why wouldn't it be able to see that the only way to escape the loop is for number to be initialized first?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is more about possible runtime problem rather than compilation. How would the compiler "know" if the uninitialized variable is something the programmer counts with? In your particular case this is not the case since your program is written in such a way that it cannot "stay uninitialized" before the value is used, but imagine you pass it as a parameter to some other method... I don't see too deeply in how the compiler works, this is pretty much the best explanation I can give.

Comment: After some googling I found details on this topic directly in Java specification, maybe this will shed some light on this issue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

Comment: That answers exactly, especially with the referenced [link on definite assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html). Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3):

You're right that `number` will never escape your loop uninitialized because of your condition on `validInput`.  But the compiler is not smart enough to figure out the whole logic and determine that it is safe.  All it sees is that this line is inside a `try-catch` block that may or may not throw an exception:

```
number = Long.parseLong(numStr);
```

...and so it sees the ***potential*** for the `number` variable to remain uninitialized, even though you can tell that this will never happen when the whole logic of your program is considered.

To fix that just assign some dummy default value when declaring your `number` variable.

```
long number = -1L; // dummy default value to reassure the compiler.
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. The compiler works so much magic all the time I just assumed that would be easy for it. Is there any way of still getting compiler-or-otherwise assistance against potential logic errors like I mentioned earlier after initializing it?

Answer (score 0):

Long.parseLong could throw an exception which will be caught in your catch block.  In this case number will not be initialized and that is why you are getting the compiler error.

Initialize number when you declare it and make sure the rest of your code is able to deal with the case where number is set to that initial value.

Comment: This isn't following the logic of my question or program, though. Yes, it will throw an exception that doesn't initialize it, but the only way of breaking out of the `while` loop to reach the `for` loop is if `validInput` is true. That can only happen after `number` is initialized exception-free. Otherwise, it will continuously loop until that happens, following the program.

Answer (score -1):

for compiler is is too heavy logic to detect
boolean condition, loop, not thrown catch;

add "number=0;" to catch clause

```
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   **number=0;**
   System.out.print("That's not an integer. ");
}
```